# PyPDF2 append file issue

Tags: python, pypdf

I need to write script that will convert images into pdfs and merge tchem into one.

I have tried to use img2pdf and PYPDF2 but I'm getting errors.
Could someone take a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
import img2pdf
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileMerger, PdfFileWriter

merger = PdfFileMerger()
path = input()

for root,dir,files in os.walk(path):
        for eachfile in files:
            if "pdf" not in eachfile:
                os.chdir(root)
                PDFfile = img2pdf.convert((eachfile,), dpi=None, x=None, y=None)
                merger.append(fileobj=PDFfile)
merger.write(open("out.pdf", "wb"))
```

ERROR

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ms/Desktop/Desktop/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    merger.append(fileobj=PDFfile)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 203, in append
    self.merge(len(self.pages), fileobj, bookmark, pages, import_bookmarks)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 133, in merge
    pdfr = PdfFileReader(fileobj, strict=self.strict)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1065, in __init__
    self.read(stream)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1660, in read
    stream.seek(-1, 2)
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Does it have something to do with files not being found for opening?

Comment: You should use the full path to your files, otherwise they cannot be found in the directory.

Comment: Can you show the error message.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I have added the error information

Comment: PDFs from images are not being saved anywhere. Maybe that is the problem for merger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`img2pdf.convert` returns bytes of the corresponding pdf file (as a string?), and not a file handler. If you read `help(merger.append)` you will see that you need to pass either a file handler or a path to the PDF file. Here is a possible solution. It's probably also possible not to generate all the intermediate PDF files.

```
import img2pdf
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileMerger, PdfFileWriter
merger = PdfFileMerger()
path = "/tmp/images"

for root,dir,files in os.walk(path):
        for eachfile in files:
            if "pdf" not in eachfile:
                os.chdir(root)
                pdfbytes = img2pdf.convert((eachfile,), dpi=None, x=None, y=None)
                pdfname = eachfile.split('.')[0]+".pdf"
                f = open(pdfname, 'wb+')
                f.write(pdfbytes)
                merger.append(fileobj=f)
                f.close()

f = open("out.pdf", "wb")
merger.write(f)
f.close()
```

By the way, it would also be much simpler to use regular tools like [convert](http://linux.die.net/man/1/convert), [pdfjam](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfjam), [pdftk](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftk).

Comment: It works with f.close() in a loop removed. I know I can use tool but its more fun to write my own :) BTW how to remove each PDF after merge and leave onle merged one?

Comment: I'd just put the bytes in an `stream = io.BytesIO(pdfbytes)`. You can then append the stream